# Access Node-Red websocket listener

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, node-red

My server has embedded node-red. I'm trying to create new websocket listener in server. But when execute this code, websockets in node-red application stops working.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
   server: server,
   path: '/test'
});

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {
   console.log('test');
});
```

Websocket in node-red admin panel:

[image]

Problem is related to:
https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/381

How access to node-red websocket and handle messages for own path?

Comment: you'd probably be better off having the secondary websocket server on a different port. or hook into the websocket server that node-red creates.

Comment: Don't want to create server on different port it isn't a solution.

Comment: Node-Red doesn't export a webscoket server instance:
https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/master/red/api/comms.js

Comment: ah ok, your question implies you already had a websocket server running that stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I thought I'd throw in that you can use the OP code in node red like this:

```
var WebSocket = global.get('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
   server: <your http(s) server>,
   path: '/'
});

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {
   node.warn('connection');
});
```

You just need to:

```
npm install ws
edit settings.js
```

under functionGlobalContext: add

```
ws:require('ws')
```

It does work, I'm using it like this because I couldn't get the websocket node to work in my configuration.

Comment: The OP is not trying to use WebSockets from a function node, they have embedded Node-RED in a larger ExpressJS app and are clashing with built in WS server